# JS / jQuery Detecting orientation change and only allow functions based on that

Tags: javascript, jquery

Little new to JS / jQuery but think ive managed to work things out so far correctly...

I enable a click function if on mobile or if on tablet (portrait) however I have noticed if on tablet I turn it to change the orientation to landscape it still lets me click and fires the functionality.

How can I adjust my code below so if changed to landscape on tablet, it won't fire the JS click stuff?

```
// mobile
var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width : 40em)");

// tablet
var isTablet = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width : 60em)");
var isTabletPortraitOnly = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width : 60em) and (orientation : portrait)");

/* mobile cart slideout */
// open the lateral panel
if(isMobile.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches){
  var $miniCart = $('#cart_over');
  var $cartLink = $('.mini-cart');
  var $siteContent = $('.top-header-container, .main-content, footer');

  $cartLink.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($miniCart.hasClass("cart-slide-in")) {
      $miniCart.addClass("cart-slide-out");
      $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-in");
    } else if ($miniCart.hasClass("cart-slide-out")) {
      $miniCart.removeClass('cart-slide-out');
      $miniCart.addClass("cart-slide-in");
    } else {
      $miniCart.addClass("cart-slide-in");
    }

    if ($siteContent.hasClass("content-slide-out")) {
      $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-in");
      $siteContent.removeClass("content-slide-out");
    } else if ($siteContent.hasClass("content-slide-in")) {
      $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-out");
      $siteContent.removeClass("content-slide-in");
    } else {
      $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-out");
    }
  });

  //clode the lateral panel
  $('#cart_close').on('click', function(event){

    if ($miniCart.hasClass("cart-slide-in")) {
      $miniCart.removeClass('cart-slide-in');
      $miniCart.addClass('cart-slide-out');
      $siteContent.removeClass("content-slide-out");
      $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-in");      
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to work this out...

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event) {
  alert('new orientation:' + orientation); 
});
```

However it returns 90 or -90 for landscape and 0 or 180 for portrait... I guess maybe close but no so I just use a if statement so if 90 or -90 do this... or is there a better way to just do if portrait or landscape?

**UPDATE 2**

I thought maybe if I add condition into a function and also set on load and orientation change might work as would check again... but not sure it is.... think I'm on the right track any ideas with the following?

```
function cartSlide(){
  if(isMobile.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches){
    var $miniCart = $('#cart_over');
    var $cartLink = $('.mini-cart');
    var $siteContent = $('.top-header-container, .main-content, footer');

    $cartLink.on('click', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      if ($miniCart.hasClass("cart-slide-in")) {
        $miniCart.addClass("cart-slide-out");
        $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-in");
      } else if ($miniCart.hasClass("cart-slide-out")) {
        $miniCart.removeClass('cart-slide-out');
        $miniCart.addClass("cart-slide-in");
      } else {
        $miniCart.addClass("cart-slide-in");
      }

      if ($siteContent.hasClass("content-slide-out")) {
        $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-in");
        $siteContent.removeClass("content-slide-out");
      } else if ($siteContent.hasClass("content-slide-in")) {
        $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-out");
        $siteContent.removeClass("content-slide-in");
      } else {
        $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-out");
      }
    });

    //clode the lateral panel
    $('#cart_close').on('click', function(event){

      if ($miniCart.hasClass("cart-slide-in")) {
        $miniCart.removeClass('cart-slide-in');
        $miniCart.addClass('cart-slide-out');
        $siteContent.removeClass("content-slide-out");
        $siteContent.addClass("content-slide-in");      
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    });
  }
}

// open the lateral panel
if(isMobile.matches || isTabletPortraitOnly.matches){
  cartSlide();
}

$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event) {
  cartSlide();
});
```

Comment: On `orientationchange` or even `resize` you could just get the screen width and height, and see which is bigger to decide if you are in portrait or landscape. Though with the code you have there, could could also just do `var orientation = Math.abs(event.orientation) === 90 ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';`

Comment: Im not sure how to approach, i am trying but without success at the moment but new with JS / jQuery.... would it be possible to get a hand? if you have a moment of course.

Comment: Ive actually placed the click function and vars into a function now so can be called within conditions easier so wont have to replicate... shall i add an update for you to see? actually i created one here: https://jsfiddle.net/692afscp/